# Ruby on Rails Session Expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Following Railstutorial.org, I have put a `Remember me` box in the login page in order to force the session not to expire only if this box is checked. However, with the following code, even if I do not check the `Remember me` box, at the time that I close the browser, the session does not expire. Where is the problem?

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a `sessions_helper` file with something like a `remember(user)` method? If so, could you add it to your post? And your `log_out` method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Rails version you are using, but you can try this:

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store expire_after: 24.hours
```

Typically, that's found in the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file. If your Rails version doesn't support this, you can manually add in an expiration like `session[:expires_after] = Time.now + 24.hours`

From what I understand, Rails doesn't let the sessions expire by default so you have to add in this logic yourself. This is why your `remember me` doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check if the problem still occurs after having called `forget`manually?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that at some point you've set the session with `remember(user)` and didn't `forget` it?

Try manually calling the forget method for the user you were using in the Rails console:

```
>> user = User.find_by(email: "example@railstutorial.org")
>> user.forget
```

Comment: `user.forget` returns true. So the problem is not from that side.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the `true` would be returned in either case. Try to log in again without remembering and log out and see if the session is still active.